# How to set the background of an Angular app to an image?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular

In my app.component.css I have

```
.container{
    background-image: url(/image.jpg);
}
```

and in app.component.html I have

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>image</h1>
</div>
```

I am confused with this is not working. Is there a better way to set a background image for the app?

Comment: what is your folder structure? is the image in the same folder? it should be url("image.jpg") if it's in the same folder as your html

Comment: where is you image. i hope its in src atleast. because your angular app root would be src folder. you can put it in assets if you want. and yes i am talking about angular 2+.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsbsub?file=src/styles.css) you should also set its width and height

```
.container{
    background-image: url(/image.jpg);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and you also set html and boys width and height too in styles.css

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9sdjfm?file=src/app/app.component.css) for you

Try using `background` like this:

**app.component.css**

```css
.img {
  background: url(imgage-url-address-here);
  height: 480px;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<p class="img">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```